# Sitecore Edit User exception in User Manager

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, usermanager

[image: Error screengrab]

I am trying to figure out what might be wrong. Basically, I am not able to edit any user accounts. Once I click Edit in User Manager I get the attached exception.

Any advise would be much appreciated.

Sitecore version is 6.6.0 (rev 130214)

here is the exception from the log file:

```
**6136 11:49:33 FATAL An uncaught exception occurred 
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException 
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. 
Source: System.Web 
at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) 

Nested Exception 

Exception: System.NullReferenceException 
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Source: Sitecore.Client 
at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Security.EditUser.EditUserPage.PlaceInFrame(String urlString) 
at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Security.EditUser.EditUserPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) 
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)**
```

Comment: Hi Igor.  Could you look in the Sitecore logs and see if there is additional information there about the exact error that is being thrown?

Comment: Have you made any changes to the file `\sitecore\shell\Applications\Security\EditUser\EditUser.xaml.xml`?

Comment: Or is there a file in \sitecore\shell\override called EditUser.xaml.xml?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks a lot for the tips. I am trying to get hold of the log files as i dont currently have access to the server (doesnt make it any easier to troubleshoot). I will confirm the rest of the information too.

Comment: @Igor If you have access to the CMS interface then `Sitecore Menu > Reporting Tools > Log Viewer`

Comment: hi all, i have added the exception to my original post.

Comment: Not very helpful :( My suggestion if you are sure it is not your code: get the zip file of the Sitecore install (from SDN), unzip and copy over the /sitecore folder

Comment: Thanks jammykamless, i replaced the whole of the shell folder as suggested and the issue disappeared. I assume it was either missing or corrupt file.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the whole of the shell folder as suggested and the issue disappeared. I assume it was either missing or corrupt file.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to replace your bin folder with fresh Sitecore dll's.